# name 'app_config' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

I just study working with Flask and don`t understand why my code is not working.
Here it is:

#run py

```
import os

from app.create_app import create_app

config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')

app = create_app(config_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#create_app.py

```
from config import app_config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

#config.py

```
class Config(object):
    """
    Common configurations
    """

    # Put any configurations here that are common across all environments


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    """
    Development configurations
    """

    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    """
    Production configurations
    """

    DEBUG = False

app_config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig
}
```

When I run my app I just get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Dess\Desktop\iv\flask\app\create_app.py", line 27, in create_app
NameError: name 'app_config' is not defined
```

I pointed out app_config in create_app, but run.py didn`t find it. I would be glad for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you should change app_config to app.config at #create.py .